# Composite view navigation in PRISM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, prism-4

I've searched online and was unable to find a specific answer to this question so I thought I'd asked. Sorry if I've missed the answer else where.

I work in an application that uses mvvm / prism framework and I'm wondering it it is possible to navigate to a view and then open a specific composite region within it allowing me to reach an end state that would normally taking clicking through a tab control.

Is this possible to do but only when I press a specific button rather than it be the default view navigation.

If so would I do with on initial navigation, or pass a parameter to the new view that says then navigate to the composite views.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't be the only person wondering this? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Regions are not controls. You can define a region in a control, say content control, and define what view will be associated with the region. Whenever the control become visible in the visual tree, the regions(the associated view) in the control will be visible.

Comment: Thanks so with that in mind I would pass the VM args when navigated to to set that specific view visible inside the tabcontrol first to override the default visual index?

Comment: Setting a specific control visible and what view you want in a region are two different things, consider it accordingly. If your region is within control which is inside a tab , the tab has to be active to show whatever is in the region.

Comment: Ok thanks. That makes scene. I would up vote your answer but I don't have enough points unfortunately.

Comment: If it answered your question please mark the answer :-)